# How do I get a negative value?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to write a function that prints out a negative value after it's been run but I keep getting just the number.

```js
const studentHolberton = (() => {
  let privateScore = 0;
  let name = null;

  function changeScoreBy(points) {
    privateScore += points;
  }

  return {
    setName: (newName) => {
      name = newName;
    },
    rewardStudent: () => {
      changeScoreBy(1);
    },
    penalizeStudent: () => {
      changeScoreBy(-1);
    },
    getScore: () => {
      return `${name}: ${privateScore}`;
    },
  };
})();

const jerry = Object.create(studentHolberton);
jerry.setName('Jerry');

//reward harry 4times
jerry.rewardStudent();
jerry.rewardStudent();
jerry.rewardStudent();
jerry.rewardStudent();

console.log(jerry.getScore());


const dray = Object.create(studentHolberton);
dray.setName('Dray');

// Reward Draco one time and penalize three times
dray.rewardStudent();
dray.penalizeStudent();
dray.penalizeStudent();
dray.penalizeStudent();

console.log(dray.getScore());
```

The expected output is
Jerry: 4
Dray: -2

but I am getting
Jerry: 4
Dray: 2

Comment: Without looking at your code: have you debugged with a debugger, stepping through the code and inspecting variables? This type of questions need to show your debugging efforts.

Comment: Your score is static / a class variable : it is the sum of the students scores (harry's 4 + 1 -3 = the 2 you're getting)

Comment: @Aaron ohh I was trying to get separate values for Draco and Harry

Answer (score 2):

`Object.create` creates a new object that uses the argument as the prototype for it.

In your particular case, this is pointless because you aren't storing any data on the object.

All the data is stored in [closed over variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) so `let privateScore` is **shared** between both the `harry` and `draco` objects.

---

To use the revealing module pattern for this, you'd need to:

1. Assign the function that is currently an IIFE to studentHogwarts
2. Call that function instead of `Object.create(...)` to create a new instance.

```js
const createStudent = () => {
  let privateScore = 0;
  let name = null;

  function changeScoreBy(points) {
    privateScore += points;
  }

  return {
    setName: (newName) => {
      name = newName;
    },
    rewardStudent: () => {
      changeScoreBy(1);
    },
    penalizeStudent: () => {
      changeScoreBy(-1);
    },
    getScore: () => {
      return `${name}: ${privateScore}`;
    },
  };
};

const alice = createStudent();
alice.setName('Alice');

//reward alice 4times
alice.rewardStudent();
alice.rewardStudent();
alice.rewardStudent();
alice.rewardStudent();

console.log(alice.getScore());

// Create an instance for Bob
const bob = createStudent()
bob.setName('Bob');

// Reward Bob one time and penalize three times
bob.rewardStudent();
bob.penalizeStudent();
bob.penalizeStudent();
bob.penalizeStudent();

console.log(bob.getScore());
```

You could also take a class based approach to this.

```js
class Student {
  #privateScore = 0;
  #name = null;

  #changeScoreBy(points) {
    this.#privateScore += points;
  }

  setName(newName) {
    this.#name = newName;
  }
  rewardStudent() {
    this.#changeScoreBy(1);
  }

  penalizeStudent() {
    this.#changeScoreBy(-1);
  }

  getScore() {
    return `${this.#name}: ${this.#privateScore}`;
  }
}

const alice = new Student();
alice.setName("Alice");

//reward alice 4times
alice.rewardStudent();
alice.rewardStudent();
alice.rewardStudent();
alice.rewardStudent();

console.log(alice.getScore());

// Create an instance for Bob
const bob = new Student();
bob.setName("Bob");

// Reward Bob one time and penalize three times
bob.rewardStudent();
bob.penalizeStudent();
bob.penalizeStudent();
bob.penalizeStudent();

console.log(bob.getScore());
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you created only 1 object with IIFE and assigned it to `studentHogwarts`. Then you use it for both students, thus actually using only 1 student. `Object::create()` doesn't change anything, just returning the same object in the both cases.

To solve the problem, remove IIFE and call the `studentHorwarst()` to create new students:

```js
const studentHogwarts = () => {
  let privateScore = 0;
  let name = null;

  function changeScoreBy(points) {
    privateScore += points;
  }

  return {
    setName: (newName) => {
      name = newName;
    },
    rewardStudent: () => {
      changeScoreBy(1);
    },
    penalizeStudent: () => {
      changeScoreBy(-1);
    },
    getScore: () => {
      return `${name}: ${privateScore}`;
    },
  };
}

const harry = studentHogwarts();
harry.setName('Harry');

//reward harry 4times
harry.rewardStudent();
harry.rewardStudent();
harry.rewardStudent();
harry.rewardStudent();

console.log(harry.getScore());

// Create an instance for Draco
const draco = studentHogwarts();
draco.setName('Draco');

// Reward Draco one time and penalize three times
draco.rewardStudent();
draco.penalizeStudent();
draco.penalizeStudent();
draco.penalizeStudent();

console.log(draco.getScore());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your private variables exist in the scope of what is used as a prototype object (first argument of `Object.create`), so both created objects share the same private variables.

I would suggest using `class` syntax with private field support.

Additionally:

- As a student is supposed to always have a name, it seems natural to have a constructor that takes their name as argument.
- As we know the class is about students, there is no need to put the word "student" in any of the method names
- As with the private field syntax it is already clear from the name it is private, there is no more need to put "private" in the field name.

```js
class Student {
    #score = 0;
    #name = null;

    #changeScoreBy(points) {
        this.#score += points;
    }

    constructor(name) {
        this.#name = name;
    }
    reward() {
        this.#changeScoreBy(1);
    }
    penalize() {
        this.#changeScoreBy(-1);
    }
    getScore() {
        return `${this.#name}: ${this.#score}`;
    }
}

const alice = new Student('Alice');

alice.reward();
alice.reward();
alice.reward();
alice.reward();

console.log(alice.getScore());

const bob = new Student('Bob');

bob.reward();
bob.penalize();
bob.penalize();
bob.penalize();

console.log(bob.getScore());
```

Answer (score -1):

While you can work with `function`s I'd argue its a good idea to do implement this the OOP way with `class` instances that save their individual score. That is what classes are made for.

```js
class StudentHogwarts {
  privateScore = 0;
  name = null;

  changeScoreBy(points) {
    this.privateScore += points;
  }

  setName(newName) {
    this.name = newName;
  }

  rewardStudent() {
    this.changeScoreBy(1);
  }

  penalizeStudent() {
    this.changeScoreBy(-1);
  }

  getScore() {
    return `${this.name}: ${this.privateScore}`;
  }
}

const harry = new StudentHogwarts();
harry.setName("Harry");

//reward harry 4times
harry.rewardStudent();
harry.rewardStudent();
harry.rewardStudent();
harry.rewardStudent();

console.log(harry.getScore());

// Create an instance for Draco
const draco = new StudentHogwarts();
draco.setName("Draco");

// Reward Draco one time and penalize three times
draco.rewardStudent();
draco.penalizeStudent();
draco.penalizeStudent();
draco.penalizeStudent();

console.log(draco.getScore());
```